# Make a shadow for top of div

Tags: html, shadow

See the link blow:
http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page218/paul-lapkin
And that demo, There is a div shadow in the "Hi, i’m Paul Lapkin, Experience Crafter from Canada." div. [Div Shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsRXt.png)

If you can, Please help me to make shadow like that.
Thanks.

Comment: It's not top shadow, but bottom shadow of the element above (`.home-main-content`)... Have you ever seen shadow on the top of element (in real world)? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's asking too much that you use your browser's developer tools (F12) and inspect the markup/CSS first before coming to StackOverflow to ask for help. You would have seen that the shadow is achieved by this simple CSS style:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using CSS

1) box-shadow
2) text-shadow

Thanks

Comment: Why text-shadow? How it's related with shadow under whole box (without text).

Comment: I suggest him to use these  2 CSS. He need to open developer tool and try which one of it work.

Comment: Any reason to trying `text-shadow`? You could add `background` too, he could try it in developer tools if it works...